# Why I can't print a value found with Prestashop debugger?

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I use the Prestashop debugger `{debuger}` to find some values to print out on my template (I use Smarty).

The debugger find a value (the material) of my product and when I try with the code below doesn't work.

**Product name:**

```
<h5 itemprop="name">
{if isset($product.pack_quantity) && $product.pack_quantity}{$product.pack_quantity|intval|cat:' x '}{/if}
<a class="product-name" href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$product.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" itemprop="url" >
{$product.name|truncate:45:'...'|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{$features.value}

// THERE IS THE CODE //
<p>{$products->features}</p> 

// I TRIED WITH THIS TOO //
<p>{features->value}</p>

</a>
</h5>
```

**Debuger result:** I want to display the "Belize Cotton & Cashmere" value
[image: debuger]

Answer (score 0):

It's because `{$features}` is an array.

This would print what you want :

```
{$features|@print_r}
```

Then to access the values :

```
    {if isset($features) && $features}
        <!-- Data sheet -->
        <section class="page-product-box">
            <h3 class="page-product-heading">{l s='Data sheet'}</h3>
            <table class="table-data-sheet">
                {foreach from=$features item=feature}
                <tr class="{cycle values="odd,even"}">
                    {if isset($feature.value)}
                    <td>{$feature.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</td>
                    <td>{$feature.value|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</td>
                    {/if}
                </tr>
                {/foreach}
            </table>
        </section>
        <!--end Data sheet -->
    {/if}
```

From product.tpl of default-bootstrap theme.

Comment: You're closed to the solution, the code above output the number "1" for each product

Comment: With your code it did not work, and on the Prestashop forum they this: in Smarty syntax {$product->features} - doesn`t work. You need use this syntax {$product.features}
$product.features - is two-dimensions array()
So, you need to use iteration method to get the properties of array. For example: foreach, while...